# sqlite3コマンドが認識されない

Tags: sqlite

ご閲覧ありがとうございます.

`SQLite`を導入して使用したいのですが、コマンドが使えません.

dllファイルインストール済み、パス通し済みです.
インストール先のファイルに移動してコマンドを実行しても「認識されていません」と出てしまいます.

原因解る方いらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけると幸いです.
よろしくお願い致しますm(_ _*)m

【keyword】
- Windows10(64bit)
- sqlite3.dll
- Precompiled Binaries for Windows sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3210000.zip (725.01 KiB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コマンドラインツールは別アーカイブになっています。sqlite-tools-win32-x86-なんとか.zipをダウンロードして取り出してください。

Comment: コマンドラインツールは別アーカイブということを全く知らず、単純に64bitだから…とだけ考えてダウンロードしておりました.丁寧なご回答ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

dllではなく、exeをdownloadしましょう。

https://sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3210000.zip

Comment: ご提示頂いたURLからexeをダウンロードしたところ、コマンドが機能しました！ お二方に同じ解決法を教えていただいたので、若干回答日時が速かった方をベストアンサーにしていただきました. (複数ベストアンサーに指定できればいいのに...TT) URLも貼り付けて頂いて、本当にありがとうございました！